# index.php displays as listing on Apache2 server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-22.04

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04

I started out by installing php 8.1

I then installed Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server

Then I added the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php php-cli php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-bcmath libapache2-mod-php
```

The command: php -v, produces:

```
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2022 13:35:25) (NTS)
```

Then I modified:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf: DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

I restarted the apache2 server.

I added an index.php file, but when I try to go to the web page, I only see the listing of index.php

```
<?php
echo 'This is a test';
```

I also have an index.html file in there:

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

When I delete index.php, and I go back to the web page, I see

```
This is a test
```

In a large bold font, as expected.

The PHP manual (as well as the answer I found on this site) refers to an httpd.conf file, and wants me to add:

```
LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
```

but I don't have an httpd.conf on Ubuntu 22.04, I have an apache2.conf in the /etc/apaache2 folder, which is a skeleton file that loads everything from various subfolders.

When I tried:

```
sudo a2enmod php
```

I got:

```
ERROR: Module php does not exist!
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

I did:

```
cd /etc/apache2
grep -R php
```

And this is what I got:

```
sites-available/default-ssl.conf:       <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
sites-available/default-ssl.conf.original:      <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
mods-enabled/dir.conf:  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
mods-available/dir.conf:    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

And doing:

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Produces the same error:

```
ERROR: Module php8.1 does not exist!
```

And grep'ing for the installed packages, I get:

```
libapache2-mod-php8.1/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libapache2-mod-php/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-bcmath/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-cli/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-common/jammy,now 2:92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-curl/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-gd/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-mbstring/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-mysql/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-xml/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-zip/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
php8.1-bcmath/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-common/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-gd/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-mbstring/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-mysql/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-opcache/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1-readline/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php8.1-xml/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1-zip/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 amd64 [installed]
php8.1/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 all [installed,automatic]
php/jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

Comment: can you show the outputs of `ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | grep php` as well as `sudo a2enmod php8.1`

Comment: Please see edits to my question. I had already tried grep.

Comment: you didn't execute the first command, the whole thing is one command, don't break it into pieces `ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-available/ | grep php`

Comment: Your command tried to search for the word php in a single folder /etc/apache2/mods-available. The command I use searched for the word php in the entire /etc/apache2 folder and all its subfolders. Your command returns nothing.

Comment: Only mine was to find files (alternatively `find /etc/apache2/ -name "*php*"`) and yours is to find text in files, right? Are you sure that the `libapache2-mod-php` package installed successfully? Because it doesn't look like you have php in mods-available, which you should.

Comment: Yes, the command ran fine. I can also run php programs directly from that serve's command line and process MySQL data from a remote server, using PHP's MySQli.

Comment: just to be on the safe side of things, can you show `apt list --installed | grep php` output?

Comment: It's telling me the packages are installed. Please see edits.

Comment: This is going to sounds a bit desperate, but since the files do not exist in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` (for whatever reason), try to uninstall the packages with `sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php*` (with asterisk at the end) and then install again with `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php8.1` (leave both names in place) and see if you get the files back.

Comment: You don't really need to do it twice. This is php 8.1, and ubuntu 22.04, so you can skip the 8.1, and the system knows what to do. My next step was going to be uninstall php altogether and then re-install from scratch.

Comment: Did you try and it didn't work or you just discarded the idea?

Comment: I mean that I already tried this and it did not work.